# Unable to start google-cloud-sdk, cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I want to log in to gke, I'm following this guide: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives

```
C:\google-cloud-sdk-308.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python>"./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud" init
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
    gcloud_main = _import_gcloud_main()
    import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main
    from googlecloudsdk.api_lib.iamcredentials import util as iamcred_util
    from googlecloudsdk.api_lib.util import apis_internal
    from googlecloudsdk.core import properties
    from googlecloudsdk.core import config
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import files as file_utils
    import logging
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
    from _weakref import (

This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or problems with your Python interpreter.

Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 or 3.5+ executable:
    C:\Users\LF\.kube\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe

If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 or 3.5+ executable.

If you are still experiencing problems, please reinstall the Cloud SDK using the instructions here:
    https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
```

Setting `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` with `set` doesn't help. I'm on Windows 10 64-bit and Python 2.7.15.

Comment: Which binary from the list have you downloaded ? I see you're trying to run `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init`. What about the previous step ? Does `.\google-cloud-sdk\install.bat` return any errors ?

Comment: @mario it's in the dir path: `google-cloud-sdk-308.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python`, `install.bat` is optional but returns same error

Comment: I downloaded the latest `google-cloud-sdk-309.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python.zip`, extracted it to `C:\ `, then ran `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init` from `C:\google-cloud-sdk-309.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python` directory and everything worked as expected. Did you try with `309` version ?

Comment: Are you running this in `cmd` or `PowerShell` ? What about its version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started to work after uninstalling Python and removing all Python related environment variables. It works flawlessly on cmd, on PowerShell it wasn't displaying anything except:

```
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Active code page: 65001
```

until I pressed ctrl+c.

Comment: I noticed that you posted your answer while I was editing mine. You probably didn't have to completely uninstall your **Python** interpreter that you've already had in your environment. Getting rid of some **Python** path related environment variables should be totally enough. Btw. you could even search where `C:\Users\LF\.kube\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe` path was set simply by running: `set | findstr "C:\Users\LF\.kube\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe"`.

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated your case on my **Windows 10** machine:

```
C:\google-cloud-sdk-308.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python> cmd /c ver
                                   

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.973]
```

but couldn't reproduce the error you encountered. I tested it on both the current version [google-cloud-sdk-309.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python.zip](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-309.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python.zip) as well as on the older one [google-cloud-sdk-308.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python.zip](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-308.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python.zip) and everything works as expected:

```
C:\google-cloud-sdk-308.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python>".\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud" --version

Google Cloud SDK 308.0.0                                                                                

bq 2.0.60                                                                                              

core 2020.08.28                                                                                        

gsutil 4.53          
                                                                               

C:\google-cloud-sdk-308.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python>".\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud" init

Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.                                

                                                                                                        

Your current configuration has been set to: [default]                                                  

                                                                                                        

You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:                                        

  gcloud init --skip-diagnostics                                                                        

                                                                                                        

Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.                                  

Checking network connection...done.                                                                    

Reachability Check passed.                                                                             

Network diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).                                                          

                                                                                                        

You must log in to continue. Would you like to log in (Y/n)?
```

One thing seems to me quite strange in your environment:

```
Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 or 3.5+ executable:
    C:\Users\LF\.kube\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe
```

As I can see you run your `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud" init` command from `C:\google-cloud-sdk-308.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python` directory.

As this zip archive already contains bundled **Python** interpreter (both 2.7 and 3.7 versions) you don't need to additionally set the path to to it for **cloud sdk**.

So the location where it tries to search for python interpreter seems a bit strange as it should use one of those two paths:

for **Python 3**:

```
C:\google-cloud-sdk-308.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython
```

for **Python 2**:

```
C:\google-cloud-sdk-308.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython2
```

❗and not:

```
C:\Users\LF\.kube\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe
```

So first I would try to unset `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` env var at all:

```
set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=
```

If this doesn't help, I would look for any other env var related with Python interpreter path:

```
set | findstr PYTHON
```

Additionally you could even search where exactly `C:\Users\LF\.kube\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe` path was set simply by running:

```
set | findstr "C:\Users\LF\.kube\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe"
```

and then unset such variable.